# Как расширить сегмент кода?

Tags: ассемблер, elf, linux

Как можно расширить сегмент кода в `ELF` файле, для того чтобы можно было вписать туда свой код? Пожалуйста, не кидайте ссылки на 50 страничные книги с описанием формата `ELF`, возможно есть программа для этого или какие-то более менее лаконичные инструкции?

Comment: Не очень понятно, когда расширить? В момент исполнения? Нет и нет. 

Или просто имеется некий файл и Вы хотите что-то в него дописать?

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от вашей конкретной задачи, о которой мы можем только догадываться, вам может помочь [Dyninst](http://www.dyninst.org/dyninst). Примерный перевод обоснования этого проекта:

> Нормальный цикл разработки программы предполагает редактирование исходного кода, сборку и последующее выполнение полученного исполняемого файла. Однако, иногда этот способ не годится. Нам может потребоваться изменить программу во время ее выполнения, без повторной сборки и компоновки. На первый взгляд, это не имеющая смысла причуда, однако есть несколько причин, требующих именно такого поведения. Например, при измерении производительности программы, может быть необходимо вставить дополнительный код в программу, чтобы понять проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Представим как может выглядеть бинарник абстрактного формата:

```
заголовок_бинарника:
   ... ; сигнатура, количество секций, адрес точки входа...
таблица_секций:
описание_первой_секции:
   .имя_секции db 8 dup (?)
   .смещение_начала dd первая_секция
   .физический_размер_секции dd вторая_секция-первая_секция ; что-то в этом роде
   .виртуальный_адрес_начала dd ?
   .виртуальный_размер_секции dd ?
   ... ; прочая не важная в данном случае информация
описание_второй_секции:
   ...
описание_третьей_секции:
   ...
...............
первая_секция:
...
вторая_секция:
...
третья_секция:
...
```

Допустим, нужно увеличить размер первой секции. Тогда как минимум нужно сдвинуть вторую и третью секции на необходимое расстояние и исправить смещения секций в таблице секций. Кроме того, возможно придется делать исправления во многих других местах.

С другой стороны, если увеличить размер последней секции, нужно "всего лишь" исправить ее размер в таблице секций (и, возможно, поле общего размер бинарника в заголовке) и исправить флаги доступа, чтобы секция стала исполнимой. Правда, если после секций идет еще какая-нибудь служебная структура, ее нужно сдвинуть.

Еще один способ - можно добавить новую секцию кода в конец бинарника. Для этого нужно увеличить на 1 поле количества секций и добавить еще одну запись в таблицу секций. В Portable Executable добавить запись достаточно просто, т.к. границы секций выровнены под энное количество байт, для новой записи места предостаточно. Как с этим обстоит дело в ELF я *пока* не в курсе.

> не кидайте ссылки на 50 страничные книги с описанием формата ELF

50 страниц - это ИМХО не так уж много, особенно если знать какая именно информация нужна.